# Toggling visibility in Jquery using Opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before I get into my question I want to state that I have been looking for help to this answer for longer than I would like to admit and what started as some a little fun website for a game has actually started to annoy the hell out of me that I cant figure it out.

Now onto the problem. I have looked online for solutions to this and have only found ways to toggle the visibility of a div/a making them disapear when made hidden, either using css or using show/hide jquery functions.

I need the space that the image takes up to remain there so it can be clicked again to toggle the visibility back again, my thought process being if I set the original opacity of the image to 0 and then when the user clicks it, it becomes visible. This works just fine, but once I click it again it won't go away.

```
var t = $(this);

$("a").click(function() {
  if ($(t.children("img:first").css('opacity') === '0')) {
    $(this).children("img:first").css("opacity", "1");
  } else if ($(t.children("img:first").css('opacity') === '1')) {
    $(this).children("img:first").css("opacity", "0");
  }
});
```

In this I am using anchor tags to make an entire area clickable. This should allow the user to click the location where the image would be, it becomes visible and then should allow the user to click it again to make it invisible.

```
<a id="image1"> 
<img src="1.png" />
</a>
```

this is how I select the image it will pick depending on the tag clicked.

Comment: `once I click it again it won't go away` - so it starts invisible?

Comment: `if ($(t.children("img:first").css('opacity') === '0'))` - should that be `if ($(t.children("img:first").css('opacity')) === '0')`

Comment: Yes it starts invisible.

Comment: I'm surprised it works once, given the  above - do you get any output in the developer tools console that may shed light on the problem?

Comment: Nothing, and at the moment it doesn't even work once. If I remove the if statement it works fine, but obviously that kinda removes the purpose.

Comment: Have you fixed the if statement like I suggested. Both are wrong

Comment: yeah hasn't actually done anything

Comment: ahh ... because the img element opacity is never '1' or '0' ... style added using css stylesheet does not add to the element itself - so, neither of those conditions will ever be true ... also, what is `t` - no idea what `this` is when you declare `t`

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/m2xkgrep/) has the concept you need - without knowing more about your HTML and the context of the code you've posted, that's as good as it gets (note, for demo purposes, the opacity is 0.25 instead of 0)

Comment: try using css hover property which will be faster . or you can use fade

Comment: @SreepathySp While using pure CSS would be most optimal, the OP most likely needs this to be a click event based on his post.

Comment: if you need click event just try fadeTo jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). **Note:** The border styling is just for demonstrative purposes.

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
  $(this).children('img:first').toggleClass('image--opaque');
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image--opaque {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="image1">
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="350" height="150" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass("transparent")` on the element. where `transparent`  class will have `opacity:0`. Adding `transition` will be more effective

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).find("img:first").toggleClass("transparent");
});
```

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).find("img:first").toggleClass("transparent");
});
```

```css
#image1 img{
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#image1 img.transparent{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="image1"> 
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e9f8e786cd329c73cd37f633d63be4de?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
</a>
<br/>
overflow content
```

Comment: -1 The OP clearly wanted to know how to toggle `opacity` *specifically*. `.toggle()` changes the `display` of an element, essentially taking it out of the flow of content. Hence, why the OP would not favor that option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a quick way to accomplish this is with a simple ternary expression in the event listener:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css({ "opacity": $(this).css("opacity") == 1 ? 0 : 1 });
});
```

Albeit being short and sweet, this may not be the most practical scenario. A class-based approach would be much more extendable into more complex scenarios. Like so:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

And then a bit of CSS to complement it:

```
a {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

There's even shorter one-liners that can be conducted with a bit of type casting, but it degradates the performance even further than a simple ternary expression.

Source: https://jsperf.app/boolean-int-conversion/2